# Can the pencil icon of the blog get its own tooltip as well?

Tags: feature-request, blog, tooltips, sidebar

The other icons in the sidebar have a tooltip, as per screenshots.

[image]
[image]

**Can the blog icon get a tooltip too?** It's feeling left out.